# Ruby - regex that matches string to pattern and detects unwanted occurrences

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to make a regex in ruby to match room number. I read my lecture notes several times but can't figure out how it works.

The regex should allow room numbers like XX.XX.XX or XX.XX.XXX (X is a digit)

Ex: `80.12.56`, `07.04.112` are accepted

`80,12,56`, `07.04:11`, `00.10.101`, `74,06.000` are not accepted

Thank you so much!

Comment: What have you tried so far? The task is rather basic requiring the knowledge of: 1) anchors, 2) special chars in regex, 3) digit pattern (shorthand character class, or a regular character class, or a POSIX character class), 4) limiting quantifiers.

Comment: `\A[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2,3}\Z`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Gotcha, `^` and `$` in Ruby match *line*  (not *string*) start/end.

Comment: \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2,3}

Comment: @Another Дима: where are the anchors?

Comment: My regex was `/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}/` and it didn't work. What would it be different with `^` and `$` ?

Comment: You need anchors. `\A` for start of the string and `\z` for the end of string. and last `\d{2}` must be `\d{2,3}` if you plan to match 2 or 3 digits. As far as I understand the anchors are the main difficulty here.

Comment: @LKPhucNguyen btw, so should 00.10.101 be accepted, or not?

Comment: It should not accepted. I have tried all the suggested solutions but none of them works.

Comment: @LKPhucNguyen i don't understand, regex should allow  XX.XX.XX or XX.XX.XXX, (00.10.101 = XX.XX.XXX), but you say that is should not

Comment: if `00.10.101` is allowed, I don't need to post here to ask. The problem is `00` or `000` in the string. I gave the examples in the post to clarify the format.

Comment: then examples are incorrect

Comment: Okay finally I figured it out. I combined my regex matching with `include?` and it worked.